# How do I edit Notepad++ folding margin?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a setting or plugin for Notepad++ that will make it look like this?
[image]

I am specifically talking about the folding margins. I would love it if all the folding margins were not on top of one another, and instead have them inside each other.

I have already seen a way to use custom language to add folds, I do not want that.

(This was Photoshop edited.)